# computed setter not working with v-model inside v-for loop

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-for, computed-properties, v-model

I have an array with multiple input-fields with v-model inside a v-for loop. One of these the fields for each array-item contains a price. In the object this price should be in cents, but in the input fields it should be in whole euro's.

I made a computed property to basically devide (getter) and multiple (setter) the price by 100.
The getter works fine, but the setter seems to not do anything.

This is my (simplified) code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in geleverd" :key="index">
      <div>
        <label for="Omschrijving">Omschrijving</label>
        <input v-model="item.naam" type="text" name="Omschrijving">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Aantal">Aantal</label>
        <input
          v-model="item.aantal"
          type="number"
          name="Aantal"
          min="0"
          step="1"
        >
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Prijs">Prijs</label>
        <input
          v-model="item.prijs"
          type="number"
          name="Prijs"
          min="0"
          step=".50"
        >
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Btw">Btw</label>
        <input
          v-model="item.btw"
          type="number"
          name="Btw"
          min="0"
          step="1"
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    factuur () {
      const foundFactuur = this.$store.state.facturen.list.find((factuur) => {
        return factuur.info.id === this.$route.params.factuur
      })
      if (foundFactuur) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foundFactuur))
      } else {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.facturen.empty))
      }
    },
    geleverd: {
      get () {
        return this.factuur.geleverd.map((item) => {
          const newPrijs = (item.prijs / 100).toFixed(2)
          return {
            aantal: item.aantal,
            naam: item.naam,
            prijs: newPrijs,
            btw: item.btw
          }
        })
      },
      set (newArray) {
        const newGeleverd = newArray.map((item) => {
          const newPrijs = (item.prijs * 100).toFixed(0)
          return {
            aantal: item.aantal,
            naam: item.naam,
            prijs: newPrijs,
            btw: item.btw
          }
        })
        this.factuur.geleverd = newGeleverd
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or is this just not possible in Vue?

I know I can probably achieve my goal by using a method which gets called @input, but a computed property seems better suited to me.

I don't really like to set up the computed property for an entire object, since I just have to modify 1 item. Any way to get around this?

Comment: The computed getter & setter looks fine, however, you are never running the setter because you are never mutating `this.geleverd` directly. _Yes_ you are mutating it's key's values, but this is not the same, hence setter will not run. 

I did not quite understand what you want to do though, multiply the changed input value by 100 all individually?

Comment: Yes, when the input value changes it should be multiplied by 100 and then stored in the geleverd-object. Would it be better to set an @input/change event on each input field and use a method to multiply the value by 100 before setting it in the object?

Comment: Yes that would work and I think that is the easiest to undersand when reading the code too.